Is there a way to do character recognition on scatter points rather than image?
Optical Character Recognition (OCR) takes as input an image and outputs the recognized characters. Is there a way to take as input a list of x,y coordinates and recognize that as characters? one way I can see this being done is to plot the points and generate an image of the graph then run OCR on it. But is there's a technique that uses coordinates only?

Depending on how dense those scatter points will be then yes. Can you please attach some examples?
